# React/Babel how to add logic in radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, babeljs

I am new to React, and I have a question on condition statements. How can I only show the texts boxes when a certain criteria is met?

For example:
When the question is asking, "Are you bringing a guest?", If they click 'yes', then the 'Guest First and Last Name" text box appears, but it is hidden if no radio button is selected or if the 'no' radio bttn is selected.

Here is my code pen of my [RSVP form](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWOxAX).

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <form className="rsvpForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Are you attending?</legend>
                <div className="mui-checkbox">
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="rsvpResponse" value="1" checked={this.state.rsvpyes} onChange={this.handleRsvpYesChange} />
                        <span>Yes</span>
                </label>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="rsvpResponse" value="0" checked={this.state.rsvpno} onChange={this.handleRsvpNoChange} />
                        <span>No</span>
                </label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div className="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
                <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleNameChange} />
                <label htmlFor="name">First and Last Name</label>
            </div>
            <div className="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
                <input type="text" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange} />
                <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
            </div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Are you bringing a guest?</legend>
                <div className="mui-checkbox">
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="rsvpGuest" value="1" checked={this.state.done || this.props.done} onChange={this.handleGuestYesChange}  />
                        <span>Yes</span>
                </label>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="rsvpGuest" value="0" checked={this.state.done || this.props.done} onChange={this.handleGuestNoChange}  />
                        <span>No</span>
                </label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div className="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
                <input type="text" value={this.state.guest} onChange={this.handleGuestChange} />
                <label htmlFor="guest">Guests First and Last Name</label>
            </div>
            <p><input type="submit" value="RSVP" className="mui-btn mui-btn--primary" /></p>
        </form>
    );
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to do that by moving the bit for the guest details in a separate function:

```
renderGuestDetails: function() {
    return (
        <div className="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
            <input type="text" value={this.state.guest} onChange={this.handleGuestChange} />
            <label htmlFor="guest">Guests First and Last Name</label>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Then render that depending on state:

```
{this.state.guestyes ? this.renderGuestDetails() : null;}
```

Also looking at your codepen, you could probably simplify your state a little bit. Instead of all the yes/no combination variables, put them each into one:

```
{ rvsp, guest }
```

Each of type bool, and just use true/false as including a guest & rsvping.